# Link works in all browsers except safari (php code)

Tags: javascript, php, html, url, safari

I've created a website which shows the files and directories of a specific folder(named documents). The user can navigate through directories and if he choose a file (pdf doc etc) it downloads it. The problem is that it works in all browsers but specifically in safari if the user chooses a file (pdf doc etc) it won't download it and a new window will pop saying for example:

> The requested URL /root/documents/2013-01-13 1Î· ÎˆÎºÏ„Î±ÎºÏ„Î· - 1Î· Î•Î£/Î ÏÎ±ÎºÏ„Î¹ÎºÎ¬ 1Î·Ï‚ Î•ÎºÏ„Î±ÎºÏ„Î·Ï‚ Î“.Î£. TÎœ.Î Î›Î—Î¡ÎŸÎ¦ÎŸÎ¡Î™ÎšÎ—Î£ ÎšÎ‘Î™ Î¤Î—Î›Î•Î Î™ÎšÎŸÎ™ÎÎ©ÎÎ™Î©Î.doc was not found on this server.

The weird letters suppose to be greek. I'm trying to figure out why and the fact that it hapens only in safari seems really weird to me. Here is the code that is responsible for the content of the links. I have put a big arrow as a comment above the code that's responsible for the links of files (it's inside "if"). Any idea would be really helpful.

```
<?php

     function convert_to( $source ){
        $encoding = mb_detect_encoding( $source, "auto" );
        if ($encoding !== 'UTF-8'){
            return mb_convert_encoding( $source, 'UTF-8','UTF-8');
        }
        else {
            return $source;
        }

    }

?>
    <div id="container">

            <img class="logo" src="images/logo.jpg" title="uop search engine" width="800" height="80" />

            <table class="tbl">
<tr>
<td>  
<p class="pl" >Πλοήγηση στα πρακτικά των συνελεύσεων</p>
</td>
<td style="text-align:right;">
<form action='' method="post">
<input type='search' id="search" name='s' autocomplete="off">
<input type='submit' id="button" value='Search' class="button1" >
</form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

            <div class="tfclear"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="container">
        <?php
            include "showresults.php";
        ?>
    </div>


    <table class="sortable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Filename</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Size <small>(KB)</small></th>
                <th>Date Modified</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
    <?php


            if (!isset($_GET['currentdirectory'])){
                $rootDirectory=opendir("./documents");
                //$currentDirectory=ROOT;
            }
            else {

                $currentDirectory = $_GET['currentdirectory'];
                $rootDirectory=opendir($currentDirectory);

            }
            //echo $currentDirectory;


            //echo $rootDirectory;
            starter($rootDirectory);




            Function starter($myDirectory){



                while($entryName=readdir($myDirectory)) {

                    $dirArray[]=$entryName;

                }


                function findexts ($filename) {
                    $filename=strtolower($filename);
                    $exts=split("[/\\.]", $filename);
                    $n=count($exts)-1;
                    $exts=$exts[$n];
                    return $exts;
                }

                closedir($myDirectory);

                $indexCount=count($dirArray);

                sort($dirArray);


              $c=0;
                for($index=0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) {
                  //echo $dirArray[$index];
                    if($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']=="hidden"){
                        $hide="";
                        $ahref="./";
                        $atext="Hide";
                    }
                    else {
                        $hide=".";
                        $ahref="./?hidden";
                        $atext="Show";
                    }
                    if(substr("$dirArray[$index]", 0, 1) != $hide) {

                        $name=$dirArray[$index];
                        $namehref=$dirArray[$index];

                        $extn=findexts($dirArray[$index]); 

                        if (!isset($_GET['currentdirectory'])){
                            $MYCDIR = "./documents";
                        }
                        else {
                            $MYCDIR = $_GET['currentdirectory'];
                            //echo $_GET['currentdirectory'];
                            $MYCDIR = iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-8",$MYCDIR);

                            if($c==0){
                            $parent="Γονικός κατάλογος";

                                                         print("
                            <tr class='$class'>
                              <td><a  href='".dirname($_SERVER[PHP_SELF])."'>".$parent."</a></td>

                            </tr>");
                            $c=1;
                            }

                        }
                       // echo mb_detect_encoding( $MYCDIR, "auto" );
                        $size=number_format(filesize($MYCDIR."/".$dirArray[$index])/1024,2). ' KB';


                        $modtime=date("M j Y g:i A", filemtime($MYCDIR."/".$dirArray[$index]));
                        $timekey=date("YmdHis", filemtime($MYCDIR."/".$dirArray[$index]));

                        switch ($extn){
                            case "png": $extn="PNG Image"; break;
                            case "jpg": $extn="JPEG Image"; break;
                            case "svg": $extn="SVG Image"; break;
                            case "gif": $extn="GIF Image"; break;
                            case "ico": $extn="Windows Icon"; break;
                            case "txt": $extn="Text File"; break;
                            case "log": $extn="Log File"; break;
                            case "htm": $extn="HTML File"; break;
                            case "php": $extn="PHP Script"; break;
                            case "js": $extn="Javascript"; break;
                            case "css": $extn="Stylesheet"; break;
                            case "pdf": $extn="PDF Document"; break;
                            case "zip": $extn="ZIP Archive"; break;
                            case "bak": $extn="Backup File"; break;
                            default: $extn=strtoupper($extn)." File"; break;
                        }

                        if(is_dir($MYCDIR."/".$dirArray[$index])) {
                            $extn="&lt;Directory&gt;"; 
                            $size=folderSize($MYCDIR."/".$dirArray[$index]); 
                            $size=number_format($size/1024,2). ' KB';
                            $class="dir";
                        } 
                        else {
                            $class="file";
                        }


                        if($name=="."){
                            $name=". (Current Directory)"; 
                            $extn="&lt;System Dir&gt;";
                        }
                        if($name==".."){
                            $name=".. (Parent Directory)"; 
                            $extn="&lt;System Dir&gt;";
                        }
                          //echo $namehref;
                          //<~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Here is the problem
                        if ($extn!="&lt;Directory&gt;"){

                            $hrefparameter = convert_to($MYCDIR."/".$namehref);
                            $hrefparameter = str_replace("./","/",$hrefparameter);
                            //echo mb_detect_encoding( $hrefparameter, "auto" );
                            print("
                            <tr class='$class'>
                              <td><a target='blank' href='".SUBFOLDER.$hrefparameter."'>".convert_to($name)."</a></td>
                              <td>$extn</td>
                              <td>$size</td>
                              <td sorttable_customkey='$timekey'>$modtime</td>
                            </tr>");
                        }
                        else {

                            $hrefparameter0 = $MYCDIR."/$namehref";
                            $hrefparameter = convert_to($MYCDIR."/$namehref");

                            print("
                            <tr class='$class'>
                              <td><a href='".SUBFOLDER."?currentdirectory=".urlencode($hrefparameter)."&cdir=".urlencode($hrefparameter0)."'>".convert_to($name)."</a></td>
                              <td>$extn</td>
                              <td>$size</td>
                              <td sorttable_customkey='$timekey'>$modtime</td>
                            </tr>");
                        }
                        //echo mb_detect_encoding( $hrefparameter, "auto" );
                    }
                }
            }

                FUNCTION folderSize($dir){
                    $count_size = 0;
                    $count = 0;
                    $dir_array = scandir($dir);
                    foreach($dir_array as $key=>$filename){
                        if($filename!=".." && $filename!="."){
                            if(is_dir($dir."/".$filename)){
                                $new_foldersize = foldersize($dir."/".$filename);
                                $count_size = $count_size+ $new_foldersize;
                        }
                        else if(is_file($dir."/".$filename)){
                            $count_size = $count_size + filesize($dir."/".$filename);
                            $count++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return $count_size;
            }


?>


    <div id="showing"></div>
    <div id="results" class="results">



    </div>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <form>
        <input 
            type='button' 
            id="button" 
            value='DownloadAll' 
            class="button2" 
            <?php if (!isset($_GET['currentdirectory'])){ $_GET['currentdirectory']=""; } ?>
            onClick="window.location='downloadZip.php?currentdirectory=<?php echo $_GET['currentdirectory']; ?>';" >
    </form>
```

Comment: php is serverside- the browser has noting to do with it

Comment: The browser could be relevant to the extent that it is, for whatever reason, requesting a different URL from the server than other browsers request.  So: what does the access log on the server say?  Can you compare with what the access log for a request from a different browser says?

Comment: Andrew for now i don't have access to the access log but i i will check it as soon as possible.

Comment: Dagon you're saying that the problem isn't for sure in the php part. So it has to be in html or javascript?

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($encoding !== 'UTF-8'){
        return mb_convert_encoding( $source, 'UTF-8','UTF-8');
    }
```

You are converting from UTF-8 encoding to UTF-8 encoding. As result safari seems to get url in unsupported encoding which seems not to handle properly.

Try:

```
if ($encoding !== 'UTF-8'){
        return mb_convert_encoding( $source, 'UTF-8','UTF-8,ISO-8859-7 ');
    }
```

> ## UPDATE

I did some  additional testing and it seems that `mb_detect_encoding()` always returns UTF-8 if "auto" is specified as attribute or no second attribute is passed. I solved this by doing that like below, but can't fully test it without the actual files and paths. Try if it works this way:

```
function convert_to( $source ){
    $encoding = mb_detect_encoding( $source, "Windows-1253,ISO-8859-7,UTF-8" );
    if ($encoding !== 'UTF-8'){
        return mb_convert_encoding( $source, 'utf-8','Windows-1253,ISO-8859-7,UTF-8');
    }
    else {
        return $source;
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried what you said but the outcome is that all directories are shown with unknown encoding(japanese) and if i choose to open a directory to see what files are inside it's empty ( all directories). thank you very much for the try :)

Comment: Also i forgot to mention that the project is running on a linux server and the coding is default utf-8.

Comment: Sory for late commenting. Are you sure that all php files are saved in UTF-8 encoding without BOM? The server runs linux, but files might not be in the correct encoding if are edited in windows via ftp or ssh.

Also, try adding `accept-charset='UTF-8'` as additional attribute to the form tag.